# handle multiple request of REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have create a rest api using api Controller in ASP.NET and performing some task that may take 10 minutes to finish task because user enter the time to finish that task. In this case  I think multiple request can't be handle.

I am using this --

```
 public class Controller : ApiController
    {
     [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("APICall")]
        public string API()
        {

            Rest y = new Rest();
            return y.APiDATA();
        }

}
```

my question is during performing this task when one more request come then does it create new thread for each request or not? if not then how to handle concurrent request .
Please help me.

```
I am getting following error when calling url after deploy in IIS
```

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","St‌​ackTrace":" at restapi.service.Rest.synthetic()\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.Ac‌​tionExecutor.<>c__Di‌​splayClass13.b__c(Ob‌​ject instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult]‌​(Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Comment: What did you investigate?

Comment: If you've got things which are very long-running, you'd probably be better queueing your requests up in a database or other storage, and then having a separate background service which actually does the processing. Web apps are not designed to execute 10 minute tasks. If you need the user to see the status of what is happening then you can write some GUI which will report any status updates which the background service gives (e.g. it could write values back into the database to indicate progress, completion, failure etc).

Comment: when i am running on localhost and calling the api then its working but after hosting on IIS as you can see the error above is coming

Comment: Probably there's some difference in the timeout settings, then. But still as I mentioned this is not a very sustainable or scalable approach in general.

Answer (score 1):

Each Web API request works its own separate thread and so multiple request will work. But you may face time out issue.

Regards
Abdul

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
means it will handle async call.

Comment: Please explain what you meant by async call, is it fire and throw Web API request from UI or Async call from web API itself. if it is time consuming process, i would recommend  to schedule backend job and trigger it from UI.

Comment: Actually  I want to handle each request by new thread so that multiple request can handle and each thread perform separate task.

Comment: when i am running on localhost and calling the api then its working but after hosting on IIS as you can see the error above.

Comment: it seems some configuration issue in IIS. Hope you mapped proper .Net framework in IIS app pool.

Answer (score 1):

Each request that comes in will be on a separate thread (Task), but also each request that comes in will be on a new instance of your Controller class.  However, you'll find that any client that doesn't get a response back within a small period of time (say 10 seconds, or maybe if you're lucky, 60 seconds), will consider it a timeout.

You probably need to park the processing somewhere else (say in a worker queue, and make sure you have a worker running that can handle it), and give back in your response a token they can use to poll for status.  Or some other means of communicating to them when the job is done.

Comment: I am getting following error


{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":" at restapi.service.Rest.synthetic()\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}